# How to get Push Notification + WebSocket on Flutter when app is closed? Without FCM or Firebase

Tags: flutter, flutter-notification

I want to make sure that notifications come when the application is closed. I'm using [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) and for WebSocket [web_socket_channel](https://pub.dev/packages/web_socket_channel).